# webMethods get the default proxy

Tags: webmethods

i'm using webMethods framework and my webService pass thought a proxy; however the used proxy depends on the specied envinroment; i would like to know if exists a webMethods flow to get default proxy that i used in my server.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: What product are you talking about? IntegrationServer? Could you please explain why you would need to know about the default proxy in your scenario? I do not understand your use case and this requirement.

Comment: I want to get the proxy setting that i've installed on the IntegrationServer

Comment: did u try WmMFT services ?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Also do not understand what exactly you need.

As far as I know all outbound webServices are using the proxies defined in Settings / Proxy server by default. 

You can specify proxies per protocols HTTP, HTTPS or FTP

Answer (score 0):

You can specify different HTTP or HTTPS proxy servers in the Integration Server. This alias can be reused in some built-in services to specify that this service must run via a specific proxy. 
There is also an extended setting that you can set for this, for more information, see the documentation for the Integration Server.